# Need help piping a curl command in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set up an ansible role that will install gitlab-ce.To add the correct repo according to their website, I run this command:

```
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

How can I translate this to ansible and be able to see the stdout from this command? Currently I have this:

```
shell: curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

Would this be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract from one of the reference roles to install gitlab-ce => https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-gitlab

```
- name: Download GitLab repository installation script.
  get_url:
    url: "{{ gitlab_repository_installation_script_url }}"
    dest: /tmp/gitlab_install_repository.sh
    validate_certs: "{{ gitlab_download_validate_certs }}"
  when: not gitlab_file.stat.exists

- name: Install GitLab repository.
  command: bash /tmp/gitlab_install_repository.sh
  when: not gitlab_file.stat.exists
```

The conditions are here to stop from installing if already done. Have a look at the role and its other tasks and default values for more info

Comment: Great idea extracting and getting the answer from a reference role! I've ended up using this method.

Comment: You might consider using the entire role since it already does the job. Reusing roles through ansible-galaxy (either public ones or private hosted on your own git) is one of the power of ansible.